# Why is my onclick event not working?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
function clear()
   {
      document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'block'; 
      document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'none';

   }
</script>

<div id="Div1">
 <p>hi</p> 
</div>
<div id="Div2">
  <p>bye</p>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="return clear()" id="Refresh">
```

While clicking the refresh button, I need to show "hi", but my script function is not working.  I'm trying to hide `Div2` and to show `Div1`, but nothing happens.

Comment: Define "not working"...

Comment: function is not calling and i checked using alert();

Answer (score 6):

There's an old deprecated function, [`document.clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear), that you appear to be clashing with.  The [current spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#dom-document-clear) defines this as:

> The clear(), captureEvents(), and releaseEvents() methods must do nothing.

If you use `clear2` for instance, it works as expected.

A better, more modern approach, would be to move your script block after your HTML content, and using an event listener to hook up to the click event, that way you don't even need a function name:

```html
<div id="Div1">
  <p>hi</p> 
</div>
<div id="Div2">
  <p>bye</p>
</div>
    
<button type="button" id="Refresh">Click</button>

<script>
    document.getElementById('Refresh').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'block'; 
        document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'none';
    });
</script>
```

In case it's not obvious, we put the script block after the HTML content so that when the script runs during page load, the `getElementById('Refresh')` is able to find the `<button>`.  If the script block was at the top, when the code runs the button wouldn't exist in the page, and it would fail to find it.

Comment: The scope of event handler content attributes is really evil.

Comment: thanku@james i understand what i did

Answer (score 1):

Ur code looks fine only change function name.. it will work for u. try any other  name

like..

```
cleardive(), clear1()
```

and write ur complete button code like below

```
<button type="button" onclick="return clear()" id="Refresh">button name </button>
```

try it.

Comment: `clear` is not a [reserved word](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reserved-words), and you can use it as a function name. The problem is the scope of internal raw uncompiled handlers.

Comment: thanku@nitesh, yes clear is default function javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function clearText()
   {
      document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'block'; 
      document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'none';

   }
</script>

<div id="Div1">
 <p>hi</p> 
</div>
<div id="Div2">
  <p>bye</p>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="return clearText()" id="Refresh">
```